# Удалить папку с файлами php

Tags: php, delete

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть папка с файлами, путь такой /home/hostru/site.ru/uploads/task/2/117/
Как удалить данную папку php?

Comment: что вам мешает погуглить?

Comment: Вы уже постили код функции которая удаляла папку с файлами. Что теперь не так?

Comment: @u_mulder не могу правильно указать папку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Должно помочь

```
function dirDel ($dir) 
{  
    $d=opendir($dir);  
    while(($entry=readdir($d))!==false) 
    { 
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") 
        { 
            if (is_dir($dir."/".$entry)) 
            {  
                dirDel($dir."/".$entry);  
            } 
            else 
            {  
                unlink ($dir."/".$entry);  
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($d);  
    rmdir ($dir);  
 }
```

Дальше вызываешь функцию (путь к папке);

Comment: "Дальше вызываешь функцию (путь к папке);"

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: dirDel('путь');

Comment: Можете показать в коде как это сделать?

Comment: Я и так код написал http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/gl5_1.php

Comment: Путь начинай от корня сайта /uploads/task/2/117/ может поможет

Comment: Не помогло, я объявил переменную $dir = "/uploads/task/2/117/";

Comment: А функцию то объявил и вызвал?

Comment: Объявил и вызвал, страница висит.

Comment: Код покажи здесь где нибудь

Comment: <?php
  function dirDel ($dir = '') 
{  
    $d=opendir($dir);  
    while(($entry=readdir($d))!==false) 
    { 
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") 
        { 
            if (is_dir($dir."/".$entry)) 
            {  
                dirDel($dir."/".$entry);  
            } 
            else 
            {  
                unlink ($dir."/".$entry);  
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($d);  
    rmdir ($dir);  
 } 
 $func = 'dirDel';
$func('/uploads/task/2/117/');   
?>

Comment: Ничего же не изменилось кроме function dirDel ($dir)

Comment: Зачем ты отредактировал функцию, там просто $dir в скобках должно быть, а что бы вызвать функцию нужно писать dirDel(тут переменная $dir) в $dir перед вызовом заносишь путь к папке просто в кавычках без скобок как ты написал

Answer (score 3):

Если в директории нет папок, только файлы

```
$dir='/home/hostru/site.ru/uploads/task/2/117/';
array_map('unlink', glob("$dir/*.*"));
rmdir($dir);
```